# How do you store list in Peewee model?

Tags: python, sqlite, orm, peewee

I created a model using the [peewee](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) ORM that looks like this:

```
class Person(Model):
username = CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
badges = ??? # No list field?

class Meta:
    database = db
```

This is the data that I will store:

```
people = [
{'username': 'user1', 'badges': ['badge 1','badge 2']},
{'username': 'user2', 'badges': ['badge 1', 'badge 2', 'badge 3']},
{'username': 'user3', 'badges': ['badge 1', 'badge 2', 'badge 3', 'badge 4']},
]
```

I wanted to store my badges in a list of strings, but there isn't a list field. How else can I do something like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define a Badge model as well and define the relationship between a badge and a person. I think what you may be looking for is a Many-to-Many relationship You can define it as follows and will have to use your queries to join the tables together.

```
class Person(Model):
    username = CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class BadgeEarned(Model):
    awardee = ForeignKey(Person)
    badge = ForeignKey(Badge)

class Badge(Model):
    description = Charfield(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

Example query with this relationship

```
query = (Person
     .select()
     .join(BadgeEarned)
     .join(Badge))
```

Edit: There is also a [many to many extension module](https://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#manytomanyfield) if you want to avoid having to write joins.